# async/await loop works as expected with axios.get but not with a required local .json file

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, axios

I really want to know what concept(s) of javascript (regarding async/await) I am missing here. I am pretty sure this is not a duplicate question.

My code is too involved to show as an example so I will attempt to describe it the best I can and show the issue in its simplest form.
The main purpose of this code is to make a set of network requests in parallel and do some actions after they all are completed. I have that working properly, the loop execution 'appears' to pause until the awaited value is returned and this is desired.

However when I use a local .json file (loaded via `require`) rather than using `axios.get`, the loop runs all the way through before the awaited value is returned. This is problematic since I am mutatating the awaited value based on the premise of the loop pausing.

```js
/* 
  Simplified as much as possible.
  Note: The code works as desired when globalOptions.useNetworkStub = false
*/
const axios = require('axios').default;

const globalOptions = {
  useNetworkStub: true
}

const getSearchByTerm = async(term) => {
  if (globalOptions.useNetworkStub) {
    const networkStub = require('./fake-response.json')
    return Promise.resolve(networkStub)
  }

  return axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
}

const getSearchesByTerms = async(terms = ['cats','dogs']) => {
  const results = []
  let result
  try {
    for (let i = 0; i < terms.length; i++) {
      const term = terms[i]
      result = await getSearchByTerm(term)
      result.data && (result.data.searchTerm = term) // The issue is here!
      results.push(result)
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return Promise.reject(`getSearchesByTerms() Failed: ${err}`)
  }

  // ... code truncated here to keep things simple ...

  return Promise.resolve(results)
}

getSearchesByTerms()
  .then((responses) => {
    let merged = {responses: []}
    for (const response of responses) {
      merged.responses.push(response.data)
    }
    console.log(`SUCCESS, data: ${JSON.stringify(merged, null, 2)}`)
  })
  .catch(e=>console.log(e))
```

fake-response.json

```json
{
  "data": {
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "title": "delectus aut autem",
  "completed": false
 }
}
```

As I metioned earlier, when axios is used the end result is correct. The first response has a key value pair of `searchTerm: 'cats'` and the second response has a key value pair of `searchTerm: 'dogs'`

When the local .json file is used both the first and second reponses have the same key value pair of `searchTerm: 'dogs'`. This is the problem.

EDIT: changed `const term = terms[i].term` to `const term = terms[i]`

ANOTHER EDIT: fixed typos in code, added data for `fake-response.json` and posted a working example of this issue [here](https://repl.it/talk/share/await-require-issue/81594) on repl.it

Comment: Is `const term = terms[i].term` correct? It looks like it should error. Should be `const term = terms[i]` or am i missing something?

Comment: The problem is probably that `require('./fake-response.json')` returns the *same* object every time, while axios would crate a new object for each response. Nothing to do with `async`/`await`.

Comment: I don't see if `fake-response.json` was changes anywhere in the code. Also it would be better to show a content of `fake-response.json`

Comment: @patriktorkildsen Thanks. I edited the code. Just a byproduct of writing out the simplified code from scratch without testing it.

Comment: @Anatoly The json response gets changed on the line `result.data && (result.data.searchTerm = term)`. `fake-response.json` is too large to show but the values in there are abitrary so it shoudnt matter.

Comment: @Bergi how would the same object being returned each time affect whether or not the loop `pauses` for the awaited value?

Comment: Well, it doesn't. The loop always pauses. But it affects how the `result.data.searchTerm = term` assignment treats the data.

Comment: I tried your code in jsfiddle. It works fin, console output is: `"SUCCESS, data: {
  "responses": [
    {
      "searchTerm": "cats"
    },
    {
      "searchTerm": "dogs"
    }
  ]
}"`. Though I removed the `config` param form the call `await getSearchByTerm(term)` because it's unknown variable

Comment: @Bergi ah I get it. Thank you.

Comment: In terms of the `async` lessons you were trying to learn with this example:
I recommend you read about [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and [Promise.allSettled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minus a few typos, your code runs -- with some issues.

```
// example.js
const axios = require('axios').default;

const globalOptions = {
  useNetworkStub: true
}

const getSearchByTerm = async function(term) {
  if (globalOptions.useNetworkStub) {
    const networkStub = require('./fake-response.json')
    return Promise.resolve(networkStub)
  }

  return axios.get('https://some-live-endpoint.com/', {params:{q: term}})
}

const getSearchesByTerms = async function(terms = ['cats','dogs']) {
  const results = []
  let result
  try {
    for (let i = 0; i < terms.length; i++) {
      const term = terms[i]
      result = await getSearchByTerm(term)
      console.log("Term: ", term, "Result: ", result); // added this log to clarify your issue
      result.data && (result.data.searchTerm = term) // The issue is here!
      results.push(result)
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return Promise.reject(`getSearchesByTerms() Failed: ${err}`)
  }

  // ... code truncated here to keep things simple ...

  return Promise.resolve(results)
}

getSearchesByTerms()
  .then((responses) => {
    let merged = {responses: []}
    for (const response of responses) {
      merged.responses.push(response.data)
    }
    console.log(`SUCCESS, data: ${JSON.stringify(merged, null, 2)}`)
  })
  .catch(e=>console.log(e))
```

And here's and example json file

```
{
    "data": {
        "payload": "Success"
    }
}
```

Here's the output you'll get:

```
Term:  cats Result:  { data: { payload: 'Success' } }
Term:  dogs Result:  { data: { payload: 'Success', searchTerm: 'cats' } }
SUCCESS, data: {
  "responses": [
    {
      "payload": "Success",
      "searchTerm": "dogs"
    },
    {
      "payload": "Success",
      "searchTerm": "dogs"
    }
  ]
}
```

The thing to notice is that your issue isn't `async` it's using a reference to the same object for both results. This is a lesson that can burn you in a lot of subtle but important ways in Javascript -- and many other languages that hide the complexity of pointers from the programmer. You should generally avoid mutating objects.

Here's a version that uses JS spread syntax to copy the object instead of mutating.

```
const axios = require('axios').default;

const globalOptions = {
  useNetworkStub: true
}

const getSearchByTerm = async function(term) {
  if (globalOptions.useNetworkStub) {
    const networkStub = require('./fake-response.json')
    return Promise.resolve(networkStub)
  }

  return axios.get('https://some-live-endpoint.com/', {params:{q: term}})
}

const getSearchesByTerms = async function(terms = ['cats','dogs']) {
  const results = []
  let result
  try {
    for (let i = 0; i < terms.length; i++) {
      const term = terms[i]
      result = await getSearchByTerm(term)
      console.log("Term: ", term, "Result: ", result); // added this log to clarify your issue
      if (result && "data" in result) {
        results.push({ data: { ...result.data, term  }}) // copies instead of mutating original object
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return Promise.reject(`getSearchesByTerms() Failed: ${err}`)
  }

  // ... code truncated here to keep things simple ...

  return Promise.resolve(results)
}

getSearchesByTerms()
  .then((responses) => {
    let merged = {responses: []}
    for (const response of responses) {
      merged.responses.push(response.data)
    }
    console.log(`SUCCESS, data: ${JSON.stringify(merged, null, 2)}`)
  })
  .catch(e=>console.log(e))
```

Here's a version that mutates in the way you were hoping it would work. The important change being that the stub has more than one objects that you can query:

```
// newExample.js
// gets a new object each time, so mutation doesn't break
const axios = require('axios').default;

const globalOptions = {
  useNetworkStub: true
}

const getSearchByTerm = async function(term) {
  if (globalOptions.useNetworkStub) {
    const networkStub = require('./fake-response.json')[term]
    return Promise.resolve(networkStub)
  }

  return axios.get('https://some-live-endpoint.com/', {params:{q: term}})
}

const getSearchesByTerms = async function(terms = ['cats','dogs']) {
  const results = []
  let result
  try {
    for (let i = 0; i < terms.length; i++) {
      const term = terms[i]
      result = await getSearchByTerm(term)
      console.log("Term: ", term, "Result: ", result); // added this log to clarify your issue
      result.data && (result.data.searchTerm = term) // no longer mutating same object
      results.push(result)
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return Promise.reject(`getSearchesByTerms() Failed: ${err}`)
  }

  // ... code truncated here to keep things simple ...

  return Promise.resolve(results)
}

getSearchesByTerms()
  .then((responses) => {
    let merged = {responses: []}
    for (const response of responses) {
      merged.responses.push(response.data)
    }
    console.log(`SUCCESS, data: ${JSON.stringify(merged, null, 2)}`)
  })
  .catch(e=>console.log(e))

// fake-response.json
{
    "cats": {
        "data": {
            "payload": "Success for cats!"
        }
    },
    "dogs": {
        "data": {
            "payload": "Success for dogs!"
        }
    }
}
```

Still. If you're worried about deep cloning -- I recommend you plan your output in a way where you don't have to mutate or clone the value:

```
// better.js
// plans output to not mutate or copy
const axios = require('axios').default;

const globalOptions = {
  useNetworkStub: true
}

const getSearchByTerm = async function(term) {
  if (globalOptions.useNetworkStub) {
    const networkStub = require('./fake-response.json')[term]
    return Promise.resolve(networkStub)
  }

  return axios.get('https://some-live-endpoint.com/', {params:{q: term}})
}

const getSearchesByTerms = async function(terms = ['cats','dogs']) {
  const results = []
  let result
  try {
    for (let i = 0; i < terms.length; i++) {
      const term = terms[i]
      result = await getSearchByTerm(term)
      console.log("Term: ", term, "Result: ", result); // added this log to clarify your issue
      if (result && "data" in result) {
        results.push({ term, data: result.data }) // doesn't copy or mutate result
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return Promise.reject(`getSearchesByTerms() Failed: ${err}`)
  }

  // ... code truncated here to keep things simple ...

  return Promise.resolve(results)
}

getSearchesByTerms()
  .then((responses) => {
    let merged = {responses: []}
    for (const response of responses) {
      merged.responses.push(response) // grabbing while response
    }
    console.log(`SUCCESS, data: ${JSON.stringify(merged, null, 2)}`)
  })
  .catch(e=>console.log(e))
```

Comment: I has a feeling this was the issue. I opted to mutate the data because the object is deep and large and it is my understanding the spread wont do a deep copy. I also thought that any utility that I could add to do a deep copy would add overhead I didnt want. Any suggestions?

Comment: I tried your fix and it works of course but I am baffled as to how the spread operator is copying an object that is nested more than one level deep. Example is [here](https://repl.it/@Devz3n/await-require-issue-fixed-2#fake-response.json) on repl.it

Comment: There are limits in multi-dimensional arrays that you can read about from [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: I added some examples that hopefully clarify.

Comment: Ah they did, thank you. Especially the last one. Simply returning a new object without copying anything.